# What happens under the hood when running testng.xml to trigger testng?

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, testng

I know what to write inside the testng.xml file. I also know several ways to trigger testng. What I want to understand is what happens when running the xml file. What underlying code are there that support us to trigger Testng by just running the file? Is it the same as running java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml command line?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

xml file is a good way to arrange data, especially data with complex meanings or structures. If you want to feed in the same amount of data to program with input arguments or command line, it can very long and tedious. The Testng runner parses the xml file in the way you implemented and use the input values to do corresponding operations.